# Difference between rendered and visible attributes of <p:dialog>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3.2 in my project. I wanted to know what is the difference between setting the ***rendered*** attribute of a `<p:dialog>` as against setting the ***visible*** attribute. When should I use either of these attributes?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `rendered` attribute is server-side and the `visible` attribute is client-side. The `rendered` attribute tells whether JSF should generate the dialog's HTML representation or not. The `visible` attribute tells whether HTML/CSS/JS should immediately show the dialog on browser's page load or not.

If the dialog isn't rendered, then you won't be able to display it by for example JavaScript `dialogWidgetVar.show()` without reloading the page or ajax-updating one of the dialog's parent components that way so that the dialog's `rendered` condition evaluates to `true`. Also the `visible` attribute won't have any effect if the dialog is not rendered simply because there's nothing being rendered to the resulting HTML output which could be shown/hidden by JavaScript.

If the dialog is rendered, then it is by default hidden. You can set `visible` to `true` to force it to display the dialog immediately whenever the page is opened. Or you can invoke JavaScript `dialogWidgetVar.show()` in some `onclick` or `oncomplete` attribute to show it.

Use the `rendered` attribute if you don't want to render the dialog at all, for example because it wouldn't ever be used anyway in the currently requested page composition.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines of functionality, but couldn't make sense out of it. Thanks for that; it makes sense now.

Comment: @BalusC i have one question. in richface rich:modalPanel, if i make modalPanel render = true then it's showing a modelpanel on screen. it's fine.
But same thing i tryed for primefaces p:dialog. 
it did't work so i replace rendered with visible tag and it's working fine for p:dialog. 
i dont understand, for this scenario why rendered not worked for primefaces dialog. where it is working fine for richfaces modelpanel.

Comment: @Jimit: the equivalent of PF dialog's `visible` attribute is RF modalPanel's `showWhenRendered`. Apparently you've set that to `true` as well.

Comment: @Baluc : Hi BalusC, concerning the `<p:dialog>` can we make it responsive? Please refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259907/is-there-anyway-to-make-the-prime-faces-dialog-as-responsive)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) for those attributes, section 3.28:

```
rendered: Boolean value to specify the rendering of the component, when set to
          false component will not be rendered [default value: TRUE]
visible:  When enabled, dialog is visible by default [default value: FALSE]
```

Comment: `visible:  When enabled, dialog is visible by default [default value: FALSE]` That is confusing o.O So it is disabled by default, it is not visible by default?

Comment: @Shredder agreed, but that's straight from de documentation :S