# Automatically show validation messages in p:dialog on validation failure

Tags: validation, jsf, dialog, primefaces

I want to present validation messages and messages from backing bean in `<p:dialog>` component. In my JSF page I have following dialog defined:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="messageDialog" id="msgDialog" modal="true" appendToBody="true">
    <h:form id="messageForm">
        <p:messages id="messagesInDialog" />
        <p:commandButton value="OK" onclick="messageDialog.hide()" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I execute the following code after appending some message in backing bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("messageDialog.show()");
```

and it works fine.

However, I also want to display bean validation messages in this dialog. Messages are appended to `<p:message>` component afer validation, but I have no idea how to display this dialog after validation failure.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `visible` attribute of `<p:dialog>` to specify whether the dialog should show up by default or not. You can check by [`FacesContext#isValidationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29) if there's a validation failure or not.

So, in a nutshell:

```
<p:dialog id="msgDialog" widgetVar="messageDialog" modal="true" appendToBody="true"
    visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
    <p:messages id="messagesInDialog" />
    <p:button value="OK" onclick="messageDialog.hide()" />
</p:dialog>
```

*(note that I simplified the unnecessary `h:form` and `p:commandButton` by a `p:button`)*

Which is then to be updated by:

```
<p:commandButton value="submit" update=":msgDialog" />
```

Or by just placing it inside a `<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">` so that it auto-updates itself on every ajax request without the need to specify it in every `update` attribute:

```
<p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
    <p:dialog id="msgDialog" widgetVar="messageDialog" modal="true" appendToBody="true"
        visible="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
        <p:messages id="messagesInDialog" />
        <p:button value="OK" onclick="messageDialog.hide()" />
    </p:dialog>
</p:outputPanel>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between rendered and visible attributes of <p:dialog>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050669/difference-between-rendered-and-visible-attributes-of-pdialog/10050924#10050924)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, to cover non-validation messages, such as those global messages which you add in the action method, rather check instead if [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) is not empty.

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}">
```

This will then show the dialog when there is *any* message. This way that `RequestContext#execute()` call is unnecessary.

Comment: This is working great,Thanks, but an Empty dialog is showing when there are not Validation errors, How do I get rid of it.?