# How to display bean validation message in modal dialog?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

For modal dialog from bean I followed this link:
[Automatically show validation messages in p:dialog on validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460572/automatically-show-validation-messages-in-pdialog-on-validation-failure)

But at the same time I want to show data-table record also. If I used action event in the button, its showing only modal message, no data table records. In case of using string function in the button, it shows only record, not validation message. How to fix this one?

Comment: You mean to ask, you want to (auto)update the `<p:dataTable>` too when the `<p:commandButton>` is invoked? Do you know you can just specify multiple client IDs in `update` attribute, separated by a space?

Comment: I gave multiple IDs in button .This is my button code .  <p:commandButton id="search" value="Search"date="dateError,emptyId,empAtendanceTable,msgDialog"action="#attendanceBean.buttonAction(actionEvent)}"                          />I updated the modal Id also . But data-table value is not displayed?