# How to validate before open a Popup in ADF?

Tags: oracle, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a jspx page in adf containing a "Command Link" and on click of Command Link, a popup opens through defined properties of "showPopupBehaviour".

But I want to validate something on click of CommandLink and if validation return True then only the Popup should open, otherwise a relevant message will appear if it return False during validation. I explored about it and tried following code to invoke Popup programmatically but not get success in it and not even any popup open on click of CommandLink.

Below is code which I have tried :

```
/* Below method "showPopup_aug" is invoked through actionListener of CommandLink */

public void showPopup_aug(ActionEvent evt_popup) {
    System.out.println("entered in showPopup_aug method");

    RichPopup popup_aug = (RichPopup)JSFUtils.findComponentInRoot("pop_aug");

    System.out.println("Popup_id="+popup_aug.getId());

    /*
    //pop_aug.PopupHints hints_aug = new RichPopup.PopupHints();

    RichPopup.PopupHints hints_aug = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
    popup_aug.show(hints_aug);       

    System.out.println("Popup-Aug opened");        

    */
    System.out.println("before calling showPopup method");

    showPopup(popup_aug, true);

    System.out.println("Popup-Aug opened"); 

}
```

Below method "showPopup" is invoked to open a popup based on parameters received from "showPopup_aug" method:

```
public static void showPopup(RichPopup pop, boolean visible) {
    try {
        System.out.println("entered in showPopup code");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (context != null && pop != null) {
            //String popupId = pop.getClientId(context);
            String popupId = pop.getId();

            System.out.println("ClientID of popup="+popupId);

            if (popupId != null) {
                System.out.println("Client PopupID is not null");

                StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
                script.append("var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent('").append(popupId).append("'); ");
                if (visible) {
                    script.append("if (!popup.isPopupVisible()) { ").append("popup.show();}");
                } else {
                    script.append("if (popup.isPopupVisible()) { ").append("popup.hide();}");
                }
                ExtendedRenderKitService erks = Service.getService(context.getRenderKit(), ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
                erks.addScript(context, script.toString());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("completion of showPopup code");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception occured in showPopup code="+e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I want to perform a validation or action before opening of adf Popup in ADF application.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'd think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460572/automatically-show-validation-messages-in-pdialog-on-validation-failure (although a PrimeFaces related Q/A) contains valuable references that you can use.

Comment: What is the problem with the code above, you can conditionally invoke showPopup based on the validation logic in showPopup_aug method!

Answer (score 0):

So your objective here is to open popup programmatic way. Why do you get the popup using JSFUtils? You can bind the af:popup to your backing bean and use it. You do not need to use javascript.

```
private RichPopup myPopup ;//bound to the UI component

 public void showOrHidePopup(RichPopup popup,Boolean visible){
 if(visible){
 RichPopup.PopupHints hints = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
   myPopup.show(hints);
 }
 else{
  myPopup.hide();
 }
```

https://coderoar.blogspot.com/2018/08/oracle-adf-show-or-hide-popup.html

So perform your validation in commandLink actionListener and call this method inside it.

Thanks,

Priya

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question, You need to validate on command link click. and If Validation returns true, then it should open the popup... other wise should show some error message.
With this understanding, my approach is..

If on action_listner, you are calling showPopup_aug, then in showPopup_aug, call the validation function, which is returning true or false (Boolean data type)...

Something like this.

```
    public boolean validateFields() {
      if()
        return true;
      else
        return false;
      }
```

In  showPopup_aug,

```
       public void showPopup_aug(ActionEvent evt_popup) {
       if(validateFields())
       {
         showPopup(popup_aug);//defination given below
       }
       else
       {
                FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage("Error Message");
                fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                FacesContext fctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                fctx.addMessage(null, fm);            
       }
     }

     public void showPopup(RichPopup popup) {
        RichPopup.PopupHints hint = new RichPopup.PopupHints();
        popup.show(hint);
     }
```

Hope this helps.