# Keep p:dialog open when a validation error occurs after non-ajax submit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces `<p:dialog>`. The dialog has an input field and a command button. The command button posts the form without ajax (e.g. to upload a file via simple mode). If there is a validation error on the input field then the `<p:message>` in the dialog shows the error correctly, however the dialog closes because of the non-ajax postback. Because I am not using ajax, I can't really use the `oncomplete` trick to keep the dialog open as answered in [Keep p:dialog open when a validation error occurs after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195756/keep-pdialog-open-when-a-validation-error-occurs-after-submit).

What are my options to keep the dialog open (or reopen) after non-ajax submit if there was a validation error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the dialog component's `visible` attribute. If this is set to `true` during render, then the page will render with the dialog opened.

E.g. if there's a [postback](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29) and [validation has failed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29):

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{facesContext.postback and facesContext.validationFailed}">
```

Or if there are more forms in the same page and you'd like to check only if dialog's own form is been [submitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html#isSubmitted%28%29):

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{dialogForm.submitted and facesContext.validationFailed}">
    <h:form binding="#{dialogForm}">
```

Note: the `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` works by default of course only if you make use of JSF builtin validation facilities (`required="true"`, `<f:validateXxx>`, etc) and/or use fullworthy `Validator` implementations. It you're for example manually validating in action method and manually adding faces messages, then this will not work, unless you implicitly call [`FacesContext#validationFailed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#validationFailed%28%29) yourself.

#### See also:

- [Difference between rendered and visible attributes of <p:dialog>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050669/difference-between-rendered-and-visible-attributes-of-pdialog/)