# How can I display a modal dialog after the preRenderView event has been executed in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I have the following in my jsf xhtml page:

```
<h:body>
 <ui:define name="metadata">
 <f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="dummy"/>
  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.getDataMethod}"/>
  <f:attribute name="param1" value="${param.param1}"></f:attribute>
  <f:attribute name="param2" value="${param.param2}"></f:attribute>
 </f:metadata>
 </ui:define>

 <p:dialog header="Modify" widgetVar="modDialog" height="650" width="1500" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" modal="true" draggable="false" hideEffect="explode">
  <p:panel id="modifyPanel">
   <c:if test="#{null != bean.databean}">
    <ui:include src="modifyData.xhtml"></ui:include>
   </c:if>
  </p:panel>
 </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

I need to display the modal dialog box after the preRenderView has been executed. And, I also need to make sure that all data will be displayed in the modal dialog box.

Comment: What do you mean by *display the modal dialog box after the preRenderView*? `preRenderView` occurs on the server and a modal dialog can only be displayed on the client (basically opened using JavaScript).

Comment: I guess OP mean that after a complete loading of page, He wants to load the modal

Comment: Hi @LaurentG thank you for your comment. Yes, I would like to load the modal after page loading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set its `visible` attribute to `true`.

```
<p:dialog ... visible="true">
```

If you intend to display it on a condition which is determined during `preRenderView`, then just bind it to a boolean bean property the usual way.

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{bean.dialogVisible}">
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between rendered and visible attributes of <p:dialog>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050669/difference-between-rendered-and-visible-attributes-of-pdialog/)