# How to conditionally show p:dialog based on backing bean condition

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

Is there any way (or a correct way) to **conditionally** show a dialog on primefaces based on a backing bean condition?
The code looks like the following:

```
<!-- dialog declaration -->
<p:dialog id="dialogTest" widgetVar="dialogTest" header="#{text['modal.header']}" modal="true" >
                <h:outputText value="Test output" />
            </p:dialog>
<!-- caller -->
<p:menuitem value="Check" actionListener="#{backingBean.performCheck}" oncomplete="PF('dialogTest').show()" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"/>
```

My backing bean looks like the following:

```
private boolean conditionFlag; // ... +getter

public void performCheck() {
    // ... access managers (database)
    this.conditionFlag = dao.check();// some check;
}
```

I just want to show the dialog in case the `conditionFlag` is `true`. How can I do something like this on `p:menuitem` after `performCheck` runs?

```
oncomplete="if (#{backingBean.conditionFlag}) { PF('dialogTest').show() }"
```

- JSF 2.0
- Primefaces 5
- Java 1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just add `update="@this"` to the `p:menuitem`. then your `oncomplete` block will work as you expect it to.

Comment: I was missing the update but not on `@this`, I provided my own answer to complete yours

Answer (score 9):

I got this to work as follows

```
<!-- dialog declaration -->
<h:form id="dialogForm">
   <p:dialog id="dialogTest" 
             widgetVar="dialogTest" 
             header="#{text['modal.header']}" 
             modal="true">
               <h:outputText value="Test output" />
   </p:dialog>
</h:form>
<!-- caller -->
<p:menuitem value="Check" 
            actionListener="#{backingBean.performCheck}" 
            oncomplete="if (#{backingBean.conditionFlag}) { PF('dialogTest').show() }"
            icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e" 
            update="@this, :dialogForm, :dialogForm:dialogTest"/>
```

The backing bean remains unaltered (as in the question).

The main difference is in the `oncomplete` attribute and the ajax `update` attribute ()

Comment: is the menuitem re-rendered with this update command? if not, forgive me but i just cannot figure out how it works. :)

Comment: the menuitem is not updated - the menuitem is independent to `dialogForm`. However I don't think it would do any harm if the form included the the menuitem (paying attention to ids and namingcontainers)

Comment: so how is the `if (#{backingBean.conditionFlag})` part updated when ajax request is completed?

Comment: I think the trick is the `oncomplete` attribute: if `onclick` is used there is no guarantee the `if (#{backingBean.conditionFlag})` executes __after__ the `actionListener` executes

Comment: i believe menuitem **must** be updated indeed. because yes, oncomplete works after the action listener, but it is not enough. if you do not update menuitem, that if clause will remain the same after initial page load.

Comment: Agreed - but I believe viewscope solves that problem

Comment: afaik, view scope is not related to that. i tried it just now, and it doesn't work if i don't update the menuitem. i believe you also update it some other way. anyway, i'm glad it worked.

Comment: Now that I think about it, your point makes perfect sense. Somehow my menuitem (the conditionFlag) is being updated in the `if` clause - despite it is working, I updated my code and added `@this` to my `update` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Just bind the boolean variable to the `visible` attribute of dialog.

```
<p:dialog id="dialogTest" visible="#{backingBean.conditionFlag}" widgetVar="dialogTest" header="#{text['modal.header']}" modal="true" >
    <h:outputText value="Test output" />
</p:dialog>
```

and then let the menu item execute as normal:

```
<p:menuitem value="Check" actionListener="#{backingBean.performCheck}" oncomplete="PF('dialogTest').show()" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e" update="dialogTest"/>
```

No extra work necessary. For best results, use a `@ViewScoped` bean.

Comment: Very nice if it works, but won't it require a full page reload? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050669/difference-between-rendered-and-visible-attributes-of-pdialog

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar-  no it won't, but good catch - I forgot to add the bit that ajax-updates the dialog

Comment: I get the difference between rendered and visible attributes - I feel it is more correct not to render at all because, in my case, the dialog will show different (server-side originated) data each time it is showed, so I'm opting by the rendered alternative

Comment: @kolossus I got it working - I noticed the ajax update was missing and that was it, going to provide my own answer - I could consider this the correct answer (because the update was missing and I noticed it when reading your comments) but the fundamentals of the answer wouldn't meet what was not working. So I'm just gonna +1 it