# confirm dialog and find it open re entering in the detail page

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a strange probleam on my JSF xthml page with ajax.
I have built an xhtml page where I first display a list of applications, then i press show detail on one on these and I show the detail of the application.
The list and the detail are in one single xhtml file, in one single form and I manage the render attribute through backingBean logic. 
So, when I change values on the detail, I press the "send movement"

```
<jfuc:commandButton id="cmdReinvia" value="Reinvia Movimento"
                        immediate="false" ajax="true"
                        disabled="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.disableWarning || gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.disableConferma}"
                        action="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.confermaReinvioMovimento}"
                        update="@form" />
```

I open the confirm dialog:

```
<jfuc:dialog modal="true" id="dlgReinviaMovimento" global="true"
    widgetVar="reinviaMovimento" resizable="false" width="275"
    visible="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.visualizzaDialogReinvia}"
    header="Conferma di Reinvio Movimento">
 <jfuc:outputPanel styleClass="cellStyle" style="text-align:justify;">
    <h:outputLabel id="otlMessaggioReinvio" value="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.messaggio}" />
    <br />
</jfuc:outputPanel>
<jfuc:outputPanel styleClass="clear" />
<br />
<jfuc:commandButton id="cmdSiReinvia" value="Si"
 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes left" icon="ui-icon-check"
 action="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.reinviaMovimento}"
 onclick="PF('reinviaMovimento').hide()"
 update="@form" />
<jfuc:commandButton id="comNoReinvia" value="No"
    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no right" icon="ui-icon-close"
                            action="#{gestioneScartiTestateDettaglio.nascondiDialogReinvia}"
                            onclick="PF('reinviaMovimento').hide()" update="@form" />
</jfuc:dialog>
```

I come back to the list. 
Then I choose to show the detail of another application and I return to the detail page: Here I find the confirm dialog Open! 
I tried in many ways to change the update attribute --> when I confirm: update the listApplicationPanel but I can't solve the problem. I need to specify the tag element to be processed in the command button tag or in the confirm dialog? I need to specify the element to update in the confirm dialog and here insert the applicationList id correct? 
I've tried to do this but I have no solution. In some cases the command button doesn't answer and the confirm dialog appears in any case. Please I need some help I'm reading every article on jsf and ajax process/update.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Replace `jfuc` by `p` and use keyword "PrimeFaces" when looking for documentation. Pay attention to `visible` attribute. That one has completely nothing to do with ajax process/update. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10050669/

Comment: Yes, that's the problem! I didn't reset to false the visible attribute when I come back to the list section. It's not a question of ajax...about jfuc, It's the framework we use but It's based on JSF 2.2. Thank you very much, I'll pay more attention in the future!